# Is it possible to override flatMap() on arrays of a particular type?

Tags: swift, swift3, flatmap

I want to override `flatMap()` on an array whose elements are a particular type.

(I have an `enum`, one of whose cases represents "null", and I want `flatMap()` to strip out array elements of that case.)

Simply copying [the declarations](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FlatMap.swift) for `flatMap()` into my project into an extension on `LazySequenceProtocol where Iterator.Element : NilExpressing` (where `NilExpressing` is a protocol my enum conforms to) doesn't do the trick—my breakpoints in the overloaded methods don't get hit.

Have I got the right `flatMap()` declarations? Is there any easier way to achieve what I want?

(I'm using Swift 3.0.1 that comes with Xcode 8.2.1, but happy to upgrade to 8.3 if that gets me anything

Comment: Please add your enum and protocol definition, and the attempted code (in other words, a [mcve]). That makes it easier for other people to reproduce and possibly fix your problem.

Comment: Why extend `LazySequenceProtocol`? You probably meant to extend `Sequence` instead.

Comment: Look at the Swift stdlib source I linked to—it looks to me that the original declarations for `flatMap()` are on `LazySequenceProtocol`. If it is indeed `Sequence` I should be extending, where do I get the signature from?

Comment: @RobertAtkins Ah, those are the lazy `flatMap(_:)` implementations that you're linking to – you want the eager variety (I assume?): https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift.gyb#L684

Comment: Aha, it's in `SequenceAlgorithms.swift.gwb`, I should have known ‍♂️